# How to add percent sign in string format and using swift language?

Tags: ios, string, swift, format

I want to get string like `"99.99%"` from `Double`,and I used format to get this:

```
let rate = 99.99999
let str = String(format: "%.2f%", rate)
// output 99.99
```

And `\%` is not allowed. So how to add percent sign in string format, please help me!

Answer (score 175, accepted):

write `%` twice:

```
rate = 99.99
let str = String(format: "%.2f%%", rate)
```

Comment: You can write it once in regex pattern string field

Comment: Anyone knows why this works and why `%` can't be escaped with a backslash?

Comment: Because % is handled and has a meaning in string format method, it is not treated as a special character by this method.

Answer (score 17):

> The % symbol has a special use in a printf statement. How would you
>   place this character as part of the output on the screen?

You can do this by using %% in the printf statement. For example, you can write printf(“10%%”) to have the output appear as 10% on the screen.

Hope it help you :)

Comment: It works.
In my case I'm using a string like "There is a %@ probability"
So the solution was: "There is a %@%% probability"